# How to use LLMChain with llm model stored in disk

Tags: large-language-model

I need to use LLMChain with locally stored model. I have below code.

```
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-large", model_kwargs={..some params}))
```

Instead of repo_id , I need to provide local path. Please advice , how can I update that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your model, but you can load `Llama` or `GPT4All` models from disk:

```
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path="/Users/rlm/Desktop/Code/llama.cpp/models/openorca-platypus2-13b.gguf.q4_0.bin",
    n_gpu_layers=1,
    n_batch=512,
    n_ctx=2048,
    f16_kv=True,  
    callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
    verbose=True,
)
```

GPT4all example:

```
from langchain.llms import GPT4All
llm = GPT4All(model="/Users/rlm/Desktop/Code/gpt4all/models/nous-hermes-13b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin")
```

Answer (score -1):

you can build you chain as you would do in Hugginface with local_files_only=True here is an exemple:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(your_tokenizer)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    your_model_PATH,
    device_map=device_map,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    max_memory=max_mem,
    quantization_config=quantization_config,
    local_files_only=True
)
```

Then you build the pipeline:

```
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model              = model, 
    tokenizer          = tokenizer, 
    max_length         = 512,
    temperature        =   0.7,
    top_p              =   0.95,
    repetition_penalty =   1.15
)
local_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)
```

Now you can feed the pipeline to Langchain:

```
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=local_llm)
```